# ADD 30 day interval inside MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, intervals

I currently have a working code that adds an order inside an event calendar, but I wan't to add the expiration date that comes with the order (30 days after the order has send).

```
    //Include db configuration file
    include 'connect.php';
    $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Insert the event data into database
    $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO events (title,date,created,modified,tht) VALUES ('".$title."','".$date."','".$currentDate."','".$currentDate."','".$date." + INTERVAL 30 DAY')");
    if($insert){
        echo 'ok';
    }else{
        echo 'err';
    }
```

Currently this code is working just fine, however shipping date is the same as expiration date, instead of the 30 days later that I want. What am I missing here?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! ***SQL Injection!*** *It's not just for breakfast any more!*

Comment: [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it in the php:

```
//Include db configuration file
include 'connect.php';
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date)));
//Insert the event data into database
$insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO events (title,date,created,modified,tht) VALUES ('".$title."','".$date."','".$currentDate."','".$currentDate."','".$endDate."')");
if($insert){
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo 'err';
}
```

or in mysql directly:

```
//Include db configuration file
include 'connect.php';
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//Insert the event data into database
$insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO events (title,date,created,modified,tht) VALUES ('".$title."','".$date."','".$currentDate."','".$currentDate."',DATE_ADD('".$date."', INTERVAL 30 DAY))");
if($insert){
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo 'err';
}
```

**I would go for the first approach** because at least the logic for calculation of the date will be only in one place - in php. Otherwise if you have difference in timezones set on your mysql and php servers you may experience difference in datetimes returned from php and mysql.
So it is better to leave the datetime logic to be in php.

Comment: Hey, thanks! It works almost, but not perfect, because now it adds 30 days to the current day, but I want it to add 30 days to $date, because that is the shipping date.

Comment: Ohh ok. I just saw that $date was undefined so replaced it with $currentDate :)

Comment: Just changed it according to your needs.